# Better way to listen for changes - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just playing around with Angular JS and would appreaciate some inputs from you master guys out there :D

What I am doing is implementing my own localization code (I know, I know, there are libraries out there and I should be using them. But understand that I am doing this improve my own understanding of the framework)

There is a select box which displays a list of languages and when I change the language, the terms get translated.

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="LanguageController">
        <div><span>Current Language: {{language}}</span></div>
        <div><span>Term 1: {{dictionary.term1}}</span></div>
        <div><span>Term 2: {{dictionary.term2}}</span></div>
        <div>
            <select ng-model="language" ng-change="changeLanguage(language)">
                <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in lanugages" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

App.js file

```
(function(){
return angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('LanguageController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.lanugages = {
            'English':{
                'term1':'This is Term 1 in English',
                'term2':'This is Term 2 in English'
            },
            'French':{
                'term1':'This is Term 1 in French',
                'term2':'This is Term 2 in French'
            },
            'Vietnamese':{
                'term1':'This is Term 1 in Vietnamese',
                'term2':'This is Term 2 in Vietnamese'
            }
        };
        $scope.language = 'English';
        $scope.dictionary = $scope.lanugages[$scope.language];

        $scope.$watch('language', function() {
            $scope.dictionary = $scope.lanugages[$scope.language];
        });

        $scope.changeLanguage = function(lang){
            $scope.language = lang;
        }

    }]);
})();
```

Notice that I have added a `$watch` statement which listens to change in `language` variable and updates the value of `dictionary` based on value of `language`.

What I want to do is to know, if there is any other (may be more sophisticated) way to listen to changes in `language` and update `dictionary` without using `$watch`

Thanks in Advance :D

-M

Comment: You should take a loot at [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Comment: hmmm? I am using ng-change only. :) What I am looking for is a way where can automatically update the value of `$scope.dictionary`  without reassigning. :) I want to know if that is possible.

Comment: You are also using watch. No need for that. All should be done in `ng-change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: in response to comments, here's another version: http://jsfiddle.net/dn3w41cx/9/

It doesn't require data work in the controller at all.

Here's the code:

javascript

```
function LanguageController($scope) {
    $scope.languages = [
        {
            name:'English',
            'term1': 'This is Term 1 in English',
                'term2': 'This is Term 2 in English'
        },
            {
                name:'French',
            'term1': 'This is Term 1 in French',
                'term2': 'This is Term 2 in French'
        },
             {
                 name:'Vietnamese',
            'term1': 'This is Term 1 in Vietnamese',
                'term2': 'This is Term 2 in Vietnamese'
        }
    ];

}
```

html

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="LanguageController">
        <div><span>Current Language: {{language.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div><span>Term 1: {{language.term1}}</span>
        </div>
        <div><span>Term 2: {{language.term2}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select ng-options="item.name for item in languages" ng-model="language" 
                    ng-init="language=languages[0]">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Old answers:

<strike>If you want nice syntax, then you can implement something like this in the changeLanguage function: http://jsfiddle.net/dn3w41cx/6/</strike>

Otherwise, you can do it without any special changes in the javascript like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dn3w41cx/5/

Comment: Thank you for your answer mate. :) What I am actually looking for is a way where I don't have to do anything to the dictionary. :)

Comment: Hey! Thanks, mate! That's exactly what I had in mind. I just had an idea that it should be handled with directives, instead of writing code for it. Thanks again. :)