# DataTables - Can't get table strings translated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, jhipster

I have a DataTable like this:

[image: JQuery DataTable]

As you can see, the translation is not working properly in my project. Some of the fields are translated, some others are not. If you click on the language button (top-right), only some of the headers of the DataTable are translated dynamically, the rest remain unchanged (don't have a clue why). Also, the buttons of the table (Previous, next, the search form) don't change when I click the Language button.

Here's the structure of the project:

Page HTML:

```
<div ng-cloak>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <span class="metlife img-responsive img-rounded"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1 translate="webclientesApp.recibo.home.title">Recibos</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <jhi-alert></jhi-alert>
    <tabla-recibos></tabla-recibos>
</div>
```

This `<tabla-polizas></tabla-polizas>` simply calls the DataTable view, tabla-recibos.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table id="tabla-recibos" class="table table-hover dataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.numRecibo">NÃºm. de pÃ³liza</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.numPoliza">Expediente</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.importe">Nombre del tomador</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.fechaPago">Nombre del asegurado</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.estado">Estado</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">{{language.emptyTable}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The whole component is managed in this directive:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('webclientesApp')
    .directive('tablaPolizas', tablaPolizas);

tablaPolizas.$inject = ['Principal', '$timeout'];


function tablaPolizas (Principal, $timeout) {
    var directive = {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla-polizas/tabla-polizas.html',
        controller: function() {

        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        link: linkFn,
    }

    return directive;


    function linkFn($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {

        Principal.identity().then(function(account) {

            var vm = $ctrl;
            vm.lenguaje = null;

            function obtenerIdioma(){
                vm.lenguaje = account.langKey;
                console.log (vm.lenguaje);
                return '../../i18n/' + vm.lenguaje +'/tablas.json'
            };

            $ctrl.dniUser = account.dni;

            $element.find('#tabla-polizas').DataTable({
                autowidth: true,
                pageLength: 5,
                ajax: {
                    url: '/api/policies/getAllPolicyByDni/dni/' + $ctrl.dniUser,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataSrc: '',
                    'error': function(jqXHR, exception){
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        200: function(){
                            console.log ('200 OK')
                        },
                        204: function(){
                            console.log('204 Sin Sin datos')
                        },
                        400: function(){
                            console.log('400 Solicitud incorrecta');
                            $('#tabla-polizas tbody')
                            .empty()
                            .append('<tr><td colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Ha ocurrido un problema al tratar de cargar las pólizas</td></tr>')
                        },
                        500: function(){
                            console.log('500 Error interno del servidor');
                            $('#tabla-polizas tbody')
                            .empty()
                            .append('<tr><td colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Ha ocurrido un problema al tratar de cargar las pólizas</td></tr>')
                        }
                    }

                },
                columns: [
                    { data: "numPoliza" },
                    { data: "primaAnual" },
                    { data: "producto" },
                    { data: "mediador" },
                    { data: "fechaEfecto" },
                    { data: "estado" }
                ],
                language: {
                    url: obtenerIdioma()
                },
            });
        });
    }
}


})();
```

And the Spanish and English translations are in the i18n folder. The **policy.json** file loads the headers of the table, among other things (such as the title of the view):

```
{
    "webclientesApp": {
        "policy" : {
            "home": {
                "title": "Policies",
                "createLabel": "Crear nuevo Policy",
                "createOrEditLabel": "Crear o editar Policy"
            },
            "created": "Un nuevo Policy ha sido creado con el identificador {{ param }}",
            "updated": "Un Policy ha sido actualizado con el identificador {{ param }}",
            "deleted": "Un Policy ha sido eliminado con el identificador {{ param }}",
            "delete": {
                "question": "Â¿Seguro que quiere eliminar Policy {{ id }}?"
            },
            "detail": {
                "title": "Policy"
            },
            "numPoliza": "Num Poliza",
            "primaAnual": "Prima Anual",
            "producto": "Producto",
            "mediador": "Mediador",
            "fechaEfecto": "Fecha Efecto",
            "estado": "Estado"
        }
    }
}
```

While the **tablas.json** loads the rest of text resources (search form, buttons of the table...):

```
{
    "emptyTable":       "No data available in table",
    "info":             "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
    "infoEmpty":        "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    "infoFiltered":     "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
    "infoPostFix":      "",
    "lengthMenu":       "Show _MENU_ entries",
    "loadingRecords":   "Loading...",
    "processing":       "Processing...",
    "search":           "Search:",
    "zeroRecords":      "No matching records found",
    "paginate": {
        "first":        "First",
        "previous":     "Previous",
        "next":         "Next",
        "last":         "Last"
    },
    "aria": {
        "sortAscending":    ": activate to sort column ascending",
        "sortDescending":   ": activate to sort column descending"
    },
    "decimal":          "",
    "thousands":        ",",
    "error": "There was a problem trying to load the receipts"   
}
```

In this state, the strings of the DataTable won't translate dynamically, if at all. I'm trying to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370715/datatables-change-language-dynamically), to destroy the table then regenerate it, but I don't know if this my solution nor how to develop it in my project. Also, I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009568/better-way-to-listen-for-changes-angularjs) question, but I don't if it relates at all to my problem. Lastly, I couldn't find any piece of advice on the docs, although I have researched in the [Internationalisation plug-ins](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/) bit.

Just in case, I have taken over this project halfway, so there are many features of AngularJS and JQuery which quite frankly don't master at all.

So, to sum it up:

How can I translate the headers, cell strings and the search form, buttons, etc. dynamically?

I'd really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Mixing JQuery and Angular is usually a bad idea, I would rather use an angular data grid like ag-grid. JHipster uses angular-translate which is a de-facto standard in angular world, so I guess you should make sure you understand how it works.

Comment: I will not blame the hole JHipster project as a mess just because I add some new logic for a task which is by default in JHipster integrated, e.g. internationalization. As Gaël pointed out I will not mix other library like JQuery especially if the job is done by default. I will recommend you to have a look at your internationalisation file, e.g. to check that you have the correct keys in your files in the language folder -I guess for you is es; and second be sure that you have build the front-end correct after making changes in i18n files i.e. gulp build or mvn -Pprod build

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Just FYI @duderoot: I was not stating that JHipster itself is a mess (shoot, it's great!), but MY project. Thus, the downvote feels a little unfair, to be honest. I tried my best to articulate the question with as much information as possible. Sorry if I was misunderstood, I'm no native English speaker.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, or **angular-datatables**,  angular directives for jQuery dataTables -> http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome which of course supports angular translate and dataTables i18n.

Comment: @davidkonrad Sweet, I'm going to check this out David, many thanks :D